# How come my program freezes up when I click calculate?

Tags: java, while-loop, integer-division

Here is my code:

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    int intInitialInvest = Integer.parseInt(this.txtInputInitialInvest.getText());
    int intAnnualInterest = Integer.parseInt(this.txtInputAnnualInterest.getText());
    int intEndingValue = Integer.parseInt(this.txtInputEndingValue.getText());                
    double dblAnnualPercent = intAnnualInterest/100;

    int count = 0;
    while (intInitialInvest < intEndingValue){
        intInitialInvest += (intInitialInvest * dblAnnualPercent);
        count += 1;
    }
    this.lblOutputYears.setText("The number of years required is " + count);
}
```

This program is supposed to calculate how many years (which is `count`) it takes for example for a cd with a value of $2000 to become $5000  with an annual interest rate of 8%. This should then return 12. What I did was create a while loop which runs until the $2000 turn into $5000 or more from interest which is expressed by `intInitialinvest += (intInitialInvest * dblAnnualPercent);`

Every time I run the program by clicking the "Calculate" button, the program freezes and doesn't do anything then I have to go into task manager to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful with **integer divisions**:

```
double dblAnnualPercent = intAnnualInterest/100;
```

causes the value of `dblAnnualPercent` to be `0.0`, and thus you run into an infinite loop. You perform an integer division (e.g `8/100=0`) *then* convert to double (`0.0`, not `0.05` as you would have expected).

```
double dblAnnualPercent = intAnnualInterest/100.;
```

should fix your bug.

Hint: **add assertions, run your problem with assertions enabled**.

```
assert(dblAnnualPercent > 0.);
```

would have saved you (assuming you run your program with `-ea`).

But also try to **solve your problem without a loop**. There is a closed form solution to your problem, using math instead of loops... that solution is **one line** only.

Comment: Oh yeah that was the problem! Can you tell me what the period after 100 does specifically? Sorry I'm just starting to learn java!

Comment: It's a floating point number instead of an integer number. Read up on integer division. Also, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If `intInitialInvest=0` or `dblAnnualPercent=0` and `intEndingValue > 0` you'll loop forever.

```
while (intInitialInvest < intEndingValue){
    intInitialInvest += (intInitialInvest * dblAnnualPercent);
    count += 1;
}
```

You have to test your values before you enter the loop, especially as you seem to read these values from some input. This is a possible attack vector, even when you assert on these values, as your algorithm breaks, when someone feeds input that makes `intInitialInvest=0` or `intAnnualInterest<100`.